# Fill missing values in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, na, missing-data, tidyr

Hey I need to fill out the missing values of a data frame. The logic is easy, if there is value in `M[i, j + 1]` then use `M[i, j + 1]`, else use `M[i, j - 1]`. But the tricky thing is I need to fill out the missing value since the beginning of the row to the column after last non-na value for each row, not only the cells near the non-empty cells.

Here is the data

```
a1 <- c('a',9,8,rep(NA,5))
a2 <- c('b',NA,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,4)
a3 <- c('c',11,6,7,NA,NA,NA,6)
M <- rbind(a1,a2,a3)
ind <- !is.na(M[,-1]) 
t <- tapply(M[,-1][ind], row(M[,-1])[ind], head, 1) 

M <- M %>%
 as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
 group_by(V1) %>%
 do(mutate(., last_non_na_col = max(apply(.,1,function(x) max(which(!is.na(x)))))))


 for (i in 1:nrow(M)) {         
  for (j in 3:(M$last_non_na_col[i]+1)) {      
    if (is.na(M[i,j])) { 
   M[i,j] = ifelse(!is.na(M[i,j+1]),M[i,j+1],(ifelse(!is.na(M[i,j-1]),M[i,j-1],t[i])))
 } }
 for (j in 2) { M[i,j] = ifelse(is.na(M[i,j]), M[i,j+1], M[i,j])}
```

}

The raw data is like this

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 a1 "a"  "9"  "8"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
 a2 "b"  NA   NA   NA   NA   "3"  NA   "4" 
 a3 "c"  "11" "6"  "7"  NA   NA   NA   "6"
```

The output of my code is the following, which is correct. Please notice that for cell M[2,5], the filled value should be 7(which is the number prior to it), not 6(the nearest number after it).

```
 V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    last_non_na_col
 <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>           <int>
1 a     9     8     8     NA    NA    NA    NA                  3
2 b     3     3     3     3     3     4     4                   8
3 c     11    6     7     7     7     6     6                   8
```

I did this in for loop. Does any one can help me to do this in tidyverse?

Thanks,

Cathy

Comment: You created the data with all columns as character.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: No, that's not. But I don't think that will influence the result, right?

Comment: It will not, but I was curious whether you know the reason

Comment: I know the reason but I have not figure out how to fix it. In for loop, it goes through each i, then each j, so if the value of M[2,5] changes, it will not change the value M[2,3] again, because the loop has passed the M[2,3]. But what I want is after M[2,5] changes, M[2,3] changes after that. I might need to try apply...

Answer (score 1):

As we have a `tbl_df`, we could use `tidyverse` methods

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(M, key, val, -V1) %>%
     group_by(V1) %>%
     fill(val, .direction = 'up') %>% 
     mutate(val = replace(val, which(is.na(val))[1], 
                         val[tail(which(!is.na(val)), 1)])) %>% 
    spread(key, val)
# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Groups:   V1 [3]
#  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 a     9     8     8     NA    NA    NA    NA   
#2 b     3     3     3     3     3     4     4    
#3 c     11    6     7     5     5     6     6
```

---

In the OP's `for` loop, we could use `na.locf` (to fill up the NA elements by the adjacent non-NA elements - from `zoo` package)

```
library(zoo)
last_non_na_col <- c(3, 8, 8)

for (i in seq_len(nrow(M))) {
   M[i, -1] <- na.locf(unlist(M[i, -1]), fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
   for (j in 3:(pmin(ncol(M), last_non_na_col[i]+1))) {      
     if (is.na(M[i,j])) { 
       M[i,j] = ifelse(!is.na(M[i,j+1]), M[i,j+1], M[i,j-1])
     }
   }   
 } 
 
M
# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Groups:   V1 [3]
#  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 a     9     8     8     NA    NA    NA    NA   
#2 b     3     3     3     3     3     4     4    
#3 c     11    6     7     5     5     6     6
```

NOTE: Here, we created the `last_non_na_col` as a `vector` instead of a separate column in the dataset for easiness in indexing

#### data

```
M <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "b", "c"), V2 = c("9", NA, "11"), 
    V3 = c("8", NA, "6"), V4 = c(NA, NA, "7"), V5 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V6 = c(NA, "3", "5"), V7 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), V8 = c(NA, "4", "6")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  vars = "V1", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, 
  labels = structure(list(
    V1 = c("a", "b", "c")), row.names = c(NA, -3L),
  class = "data.frame", vars = "V1", drop = TRUE, .Names = "V1"))
```

Comment: Hey Akrun, thanks so much for your reply. It works well in this case. But the rule is, if  is.na(M[i,j]), use the value in M[i,j+1], else use M[i,j-1]. But in your code, I think it only says use the the value after the missing cells. I just updated the raw data and updated my for loop. It works well now. But it would be great if you can tell me how to get the result in tidyverse. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Cathy Have you looked at the updated `for` loop code in the post

Comment: Hi Akrun, I updated my for loop and it gave me what I want now. But would you please tell me how to realize this in tidyverse? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please note that I updated the raw data to make it more general. Thanks,

Comment: @Cathy That will be a problem with the tidyverse approach because it gets updated all at once before checking for the next loop update\

Comment: I agree. Sometimes, I am so confused about when should I use tidyverse and when should I manipulate on the df/matrix directly using for loop...

Comment: @Cathy Probably, this will be better with `for` loop.